# Type Mismatch error trying to move data to various worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move data from a worksheet called Raw_Data to various other worksheets based on values in column A. I'm getting a type mismatch when finding the last row in the target worksheet. Does `.worksheets().cells().end().row` not return a number? I've noted the line where the "type mismatch" error is being thrown. Here's the code:

```
Sub MoveDataToWorksheet()

Dim i As Variant
Dim pname As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim wslastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim count As Long
Dim rawdata As Worksheet

Set rawdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw_Data")
lastrow = rawdata.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = rawdata.Range("a5:a" & lastrow)

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Raw_Data" Or ws.Name = "Charts" Or _
    ws.Name = "Tables" Then
    'skips the sheets I want to keep
    Else
        wslastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
        If wslastrow >= 5 Then
            ws.Range("a5:r" & wslastrow).Delete
        Else
            ws.Range("a5:r" & 6).Delete
        End If
    End If
Next ws

For Each i In rng
    pname = Cells(i.Row, "a").Value

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If pname = ws.Name Then
            wslastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
            i.EntireRow.Copy
            ws.Cells(wslastrow, "a").PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next ws

        If pname = "South Carolina" Then
            i.EntireRow.Copy
            wslastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SC).Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SC).Cells(wslastrow, "a").PasteSpecial
        End If

        If pname = "Saudi Arabia" Then
            i.EntireRow.Copy
            wslastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(KSA).Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1    'Error on this line but I imagine it will also be on the other wslastrow lines too.
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(KSA).Cells(wslastrow, "a").PasteSpecial
        End If

        If pname = "United Arab Emerites" Then
            i.EntireRow.Copy
            wslastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UAE).Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(UAE).Cells(wslastrow, "a").PasteSpecial
        End If
Next i

'code to fix formulas
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `KSA`??

Comment: stands for Kingdom of Saudi Arabia. I only call out those three because they have spaces in the raw data. There are a bunch of others I'm using that don't so the first loop should take care of those.

Comment: Yeah but right now it is an undeclared variable. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. If the worksheet is actually named `KSA`, then the name goes in quotes: `"KSA"`.

Comment: Definitely KSA, you probably just need `""` around your sheet names in the code, assuming your sheets are called "KSA" etc.

Comment: Well now I feel dumb. Of course they need quotes. Thank you both!!!

Comment: That totally fixed it. Wish I could upvote the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace these:

- SC
- KSA
- UAE

with these (within your brackets):

- "SC"
- "KSA"
- "UAE"

if you really have got Worksheets with these names...